# React Native Responsiveness for all Screens

Tags: react-native

So i have 2 issues :

1. DPis and how to handle them
2. Make static values dynamic (fontSizes-borderRadius)

For the first one i found that i must use `PixelRatio` is that right ?

Im confused about all the methods it have ,what i must use and where(what i use for images-fontSizes etc).
Also what happening when need to handle my screen size too in static values like borderRadius and fontSizes with that library.

For the second one i found **3** packages :

- react-native-responsive-fontsize
- react-native-responsive-screen
- react-native-size-matters

And also i found some "techniques" but in every forum i see something different...divide this by this etc.

Can someone explain with simple words how i can achieve those two?

Answer (score 0):

React Native largely handles pixel densities for you - you can read about this in the [docs for PixelRatio](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/pixelratio). Unless you have an issue with a device that displays pixels very differently (which I never have), or you have a remote resource that can serve up an image at a requested size, it's safe to forget about the device's pixel density.

Responsive design on the other hand is something that has many general guidelines but will be different for each app. If you want design to change on different screen sizes, query the screen size with `Dimensions.get('window')` and use values that look good to you. You can do this for example with a custom Text component:

```
// if you allow for device rotation, you might move this inside the component so it recalculates when orientation changes. Or not
const sizeMultiplier = (() => {
  const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
  if (width > 2000) return 2;
  if (width > 1000) return 1.5:
  return 1;
})(); 

const CustomText = ({ style, ...textProps }) => {
  return (
    <Text
      style={{
        ...style,
        fontSize: (style.fontSize ?? 12) * sizeMultiplier,
      }}
      {...textProps}
    />
  );
};
```

Don't forget that users can also change font size in the device's OS. If you have Text that breaks your design if it's larger, you can use the `maxFontMultiplier` prop to restrict this. Or you can change your design based on `PixelRatio.getFontScale()`.

These are all very general suggestions because how you handle responsive design is up to you. I haven't used the packages you're asking about, so I can't comment on them, but it's hard for me to imagine a package doing this very case-dependent work in a way that solves more problems than it creates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , so there is not exactly 100% one safe way do to it i guess... i dont want something specific just a simply design i dont understand why in many comments i see this(the design its up on the developer) , i mean every one just wants a responsive app right,so why there is 1-2-3 normal steps to do it for all? I just have an app like e-library for my university exams and im trying to make a normal responsive app, nothing fancy ... sorry if my comment seems kind of aggressive im just dissapointed thats all ... i tell it in a nice way :) And thanks for the text tip :)